# MongoDB - inserting array object with computed values

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i'm implementing a money distribution system with Java 11/ Spring 2.7 and Mongo Atlas 5.0
The structure of my documents is as follows:

```json
{   _id:id_1,
    detail:{ amount:500.00, units:50},
    users:[
        {user:1, name:"User 1"},
        {user:2, name:"User 2"}
    ],
    paymens:[]
},
{   _id:id_2,
    detail:{ amount:200.00, units:50 },
    users:[],
    paymens:[]
}
```

After some processing, i want to add the following item to the payments array, with computed values, in the way:

```json
{    payment_code:xxxx,
     distributed: true|false  = <user list is / is not empty>,
     the_amount: detail.amount * <percentage received>
}
```

So, if i receive e.g. a percentage of 20% (0.2) , i want to get

```json
{_id:id_1,
   ...
   payments:[
     0:{payment_code:1,
        distributed: true,
        the_amount:  100.0
     }
    ]
},
{_id:id_2,
   ...
   payments:[
     0:{payment_code:1,
        distributed: false,
        the_amount:  40.0
     }
   ]
}
```

As far as i can, after many tries, with mongo client api and Spring mongo api, i got this results:

```
{    ....
   payments:[
    0:{  payment_code:1234,
      distributed: {
        $gt:[
           0:{$size:"users"}
           1: 0
        ]},
        the_amount:{
          $multiply:[
             0:"detail.amount"
             1:"0.2"
          ]
        }
   ]
}
```

Sample code , Spring api:

```java
mongoTemplate.bulkOps(BulkMode.UNORDERED, "theCollection").updateMulti(  
    new Query(...), 
    new Update().set("payments.0.payment_code", 1234)
       .set("payments.0.distributed", ComparisonOperators.valueOf(Size.lengthOfArray("users")).greaterThanValue(0l))
       .set("payments.0.the_amount", ArithmeticOperators.Multiply.valueOf("detail.amount").multiplyBy(new BigDecimal("0.2")) 
).execute();
```

Comment: So, what is the issue with your current attempt?

Comment: The pipeline of the update sentence is not being executed, and the values are inserted literally as is